# Can't access "this" from only one method

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, binding, this

I'm just missing something (which is terrible considering the kind of thing I'm missing) about "this". I have a class for log formatting. In only one method, which is intended only for debugging/testing, "this" turns out to be undefined. I removed almost everything for demonstration purposes only. The code goes as following:

```
class LogFormatter {

  constructor(source) {
    // nothing relevant.
  }

  formatted() {
    return 'returns a formatted string whatever';
  }

  clog(message, sub) {
    console.log(this.formatted());
  }

  // made only for testing
  showThis() {
    console.log(this);
  }

}
```

And it is used like this:

```
const
  LogFormatter = require('log-formatter'),
  lgf = new LogFormatter('asd');

  lgf.clog('whatever');
```

If I access `this` from `formatted` method, or even by calling `showThis`, it works just fine. So it does not seems to be something related to `console.log`.
When I call `clog` method, the next error is thrown:

```
    console.log(this.formatted());
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatted' of undefined
```

So, only in `clog` method, "this" is undefined. So what's the elephant in front of my that I'm not seeing? :)
EDIT: Note that if I add a console.log(this) inside the formatted method, works fine too.

Also, I've noticed that if I -try to- create a new object from LogFormatter this way:

```
const
  LogFormatter = new require('log-formatter')('whatever')
```

Throws an exception, saying that I cant execute LogFormatter without new keyword, which AFAIK, should work, given the fact that the class is the only thing being exported via `module.exports = LogFormatter`. Also, I did not have this problem using good old constructor functions syntax.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The code that you provided works when I run it. Are you definitely calling `clog()` using: `lgf.clog('whatever')`. PS: I did have to change `require('log-formatter')` to use `'./log-formatter'`, but I think that's unrelated to your issue

Comment: It is the exact same code (I copy pasted it). I'm using Node v14.5.0, btw. Don't know if there may be a bug related to it? It is just a pretty basic stuff, that's why I'm so confused. Should work.
EDIT: Yep, I also used another path format too. But, did not changed anything.
Thanks!

Comment: See if you can recreate your issue here on a repl or another sandbox environment. I've added your code, changing the require, and it seems to work: https://repl.it/repls/BumpyElderlySet

Comment: Works fine there! I don't know about Node's internals, but, could be related to some kind of bug? If I enter the node prompt and execute the same code, it works though.

Comment: Yeah, could be a bug. I don't know much about node's internals either so don't know what might be causing it

Comment: This `const LogFormatter = new require('log-formatter')('whatever')` probably needs parens like: `const LogFormatter = new (require('log-formatter'))('whatever')`.